# How to extend and convert a conference paper into a journal submission?

Tags: publications, writing, paper-submission

I have been asked to develop an extended version of an accepted conference paper. This extended version will be submitted to a journal for review.

Please tell me how to develop the same. Is there any need to provide complete/partial results in this extended version?

Is it insufficient to further improve the idea instead of presenting the results?

Comment: Is the (full) paper set to be published in conference proceedings? That would make a big difference in the answers. Assuming this is not a specialty like computer science where a lot of stuff is presented in conferences only rather than journals.

Answer (score 12):

This varies from journal to journal. For example, in some subfields of CS (where this comes up all the time), the informal rule is that the journal version should have at least 30% new content (including new experiments, new algorithms and so on), and this new content should be identified clearly in a cover letter. In other subfields (like in theory) the expectation is that all proofs will be presented in full detail (no sketches), but new results are not necessary.

So it depends greatly on the subfield and the journal. As always, when in doubt, **ask** the editor of the journal, or colleagues who've submitted there before.

Answer (score 6):

The key is to have some added value in the journal paper with respect to your already accepted conference paper. Typically extended versions take the results in the initial paper a few steps further, Ideally, extended versions are more thorough with regards to theory but may alternatively including a new set of experiments to corroborate the original work published shown at a conference.

Partial results are less commonly introduced in such papers (in my field). Conference papers tend to be brief or discuss early results of novel work, so often some relevant material is omitted in them, which can then be placed in extended versions. This depends heavily on your field of study, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I think one need at least to rewrite Title, Abstract and Introduction and Related Work. The key is Rewriting in new word no merely adding new sentences. You think you want to revise your Conference version paper as a new improved detailed version.